# keeping the same size of two button while resizing screen

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap-3, resize, height

I'm using bootstrap and I have an issue with the size of my buttons. 
When I resize my screen (browser) then obviously the size of the buttons change but not uniformly.

Is there an easy way to keep the same size, i.e. they grow bigger (same height) at the same time ? Or any other good practice is welcomed..

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/udr63mqt/

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="max-width:1360px">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn-block btn-lg alert-info" id="button_add_info">
                <span class="btn-image glyphicon glyphicon-pencil push-left"></span>
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.<small> Quibusdam, magni, doloribus.</small></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn-block btn-lg alert-info" id="button_add_info">
                <span class="btn-image glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?<small> Quibusdam, magni, doloribus, possimus eum sapiente.</small></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#button_add_info {
background-color:lavender;
border-radius: 0px;
text-shadow:none;
border:none;
box-shadow:none;}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can set a height and a width for various screen sizes:  https://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/wyt8uy0k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/wyt8uy0k/

This option would be to set a height and a width to your css for the buttons to make them stop resizing at whatever widths you like.  Doing so will override the default Bootstrap height and width values:

```
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
    #button_add_info {
        background-color:lavender;
        border-radius: 0px;
        text-shadow:none;
        border:none;
        box-shadow:none;
        height:300px;
        width:250px;
    }
}

#button_add_info {
        background-color:lavender;
        border-radius: 0px;
        text-shadow:none;
        border:none;
        box-shadow:none;
        height:200px;
        width:150px;
    }
```

Comment: not exactly because with a fixed height of 150px, the text goes out of the borders with very small screens (e.g. iPhone 4 with google Developper Tools). Thanks.

Comment: I was giving those heights and widths as examples, but you ought to be able to adjust them to whatever sizes you're looking for.  You can also adjust the font size by doing the same thing.  Will that do it, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I divided the text and included a .hidden-xs to avoid having too big buttons on small screens. So everything is ok. Thanks